# Rename Files with Index(Excel)

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Anyone have any ideas on how to rename files by finding an association with an index file?

I have a file/folder structure like the following:
Folder name = "Doe, John EO11-123"
Several files under this folder

The index file(MS Excel) has several columns.  It contains the names in 2 columns(First and Last).  It also has a column containing the number EO11-123.

What I would like to do is write maybe a script to look at the folder names in a directory, compare/find an associated value in the index file(like that number EO11-123) and then rename all the files under the folder using a 4th column value in the index.

So,

Folder name = "Doe, John EO11-123", index column1 contains same value "EO11-123", use column2 value "111111_000000" and rename all the files under that directory folder to "111111_000000_0", "111111_000000_1", "111111_000000_2" and so on.

This possible with powershell or vbscript?

Comment: Will folder names always be in that format? 'LastName, FirstName ID#' if so this should be simple enough to do. I would personally use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b) from the MS Script Gallery to import the data into PowerShell though for easier reference.

Comment: Yes folder names are all in that format.  Is there a reason to import the file into PowerShell?  Advantage?  How would I go about using that imported data to rename the files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer your questions in your comment first. Importing the data into PowerShell allows you to make an array in powershell that you can match against, or better yet make a HashTable to reference for your renaming purposes. I'll get into that later, but it's way better than trying to have PowerShell talk to Excel and use Excel's search functions because this way it's all in PowerShell and there's no third party application dependencies. As for importing, that script is a function that you can load into your current session, so you run that function and it will automatically take care of the import for you (it opens Excel, then opens the XLS(x) file, saves it as a temp CSV file, closes Excel, imports that CSV file into PowerShell, and then deletes the temp file).

Now, you did not state what your XLS file looks like, so I'm going to assume it's got a header row, and looks something like this:

```
FirstName   |  Last Name   |  Identifier   |  FileCode  
Joe         |  Shmoe       |  XA22-573     |  JS573
John        |  Doe         |  EO11-123     |  JD123
```

If that's not your format, you'll need to either adapt my code, or your file, or both.

So, how do we do this? First, download, save, and if needed unblock the script to [Import-XLS](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b). Then we will dot source that file to load the function into the current PowerShell session. Once we have the function we will run it and assign the results to a variable. Then we can make an empty hashtable, and for each record in the imported array create an entry in the hashtable where the 'Identifier' property (in your example above that would be the one that has the value "EO11-123" in it), make that the Key, then make the entire record the value. So, so far we have this:

```
#Load function into current session
. C:\Path\To\Import-XLS.ps1

$RefArray = Import-XLS C:\Path\To\file.xls
$RefHash = @{}

$RefArray | ForEach( $RefHash.Add($_.Identifier, $_)}
```

Now you should be able to reference the identifier to access any of the properties for the associated record such as:

```
PS C:\> $RefHash['EO11-123'].FileCode

JD123
```

Now, we just need to extract that name from the folder, and rename all the files in it. Pretty straight forward from here.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\Path\to\Folders -directory | Where{$_.Name -match "(?<= )(\S+)$"}|
    ForEach{
        $Files = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName
        $NewName = $RefHash['$($Matches[1])'].FileCode
        For($i = 1;$i -lt $files.count;$i++){
            $Files[$i] | Rename-Item -New "$NewName_$i"
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Ok, let's break down the rename process here. It is a lot of piping here, so I'll try and take it step by step. First off we have Get-ChildItem that gets a list of folders for the path you specify. That part's straight forward enough. Then it pipes to a Where statement, that filters the results checking each one's name to see if it matches the Regular Expression "(?<= )(\S+)$". If you are unfamiliar with how regular expressions work you can see a fairly good breakdown of it at https://regex101.com/r/zW8sW1/1. What that does is matches any folders that have more than one "word" in the name, and captures the last "word". It saves that in the automatic variable `$Matches`, and since it captured text, that gets assigned to `$Matches[1]`. Now the code breaks down here because your CSV isn't laid out like I had assumed, and you want the files named differently. We'll have to make some adjustments on the fly.

So, those folder that pass the filter will get piped into a `ForEach` loop (which I had a typo in previously and had a `(` instead of `{`, that's fixed now). So for each of those folders it starts off by getting a list of files within that folder and assigning them to the variable `$Files`. It also sets up the `$NewName` variable, but since you don't have a column in your CSV named 'FileCode' that line won't work for you. It uses the `$Matches` automatic variable that I mentioned earlier to reference the hashtable that we setup with all of the Identifier codes, and then looks at a property of that specific record to setup the new name to assign to files. Since what you want and what I assumed are different, and your CSV has different properties we'll re-work both the previous `Where` statement, and this line a little bit. Here's how that bit of the script will now read:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\Path\to\Folders -directory | Where{$_.Name -match "^(.+?), .*? (\S+)$"}|
    ForEach{
        $Files = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName
        $NewName = $Matches[2] + "_" + $Matches[1]
```

That now matches the folder name in the `Where` statement and captures 2 things. The first thing it grabs is everything at the beginning of the name before the comma. Then it skips everything until it gets tho the last piece of text at the end of the name and captures everything after the last space. New breakdown on RegEx101: https://regex101.com/r/zW8sW1/2

So you want the ID_LName, which can be gotten from the folder name, there's really no need to even use your CSV file at this point I don't think. We build the new name of the files based off the automatic `$Matches` variable using the second capture group and the first capture group and putting an underscore between them. Then we just iterate through the files with a `For` loop basing it off how many files were found. So we start with the first file in the array `$Files` (record 0), add that to the `$NewName` with an underscore, and use that to rename the file.

Comment: Can you break down the last part.  Explain what everything is doing in the rename portion of script?  I want to understand this better.  I'm going to attempt to adapt your code as I only have 3 columns.  FNAME, LNAME, Identifier.  I can't see what the NewName would end up being.  I will be renaming to: "LNAME_IAD"

Comment: Got the hash figured out.  Now I just need answer to question1 above on what the renaming is doing.  It's finding my file folders with the identifier and its renaming the files underneath.  Problem is its not renaming them to "Identifier_LastName.pdf"

Comment: Sorry, got into work kind of late today so I haven't had a chance to really look at this until just now. Let me edit my answer to see if I can better explain the rename part.

Comment: This line isn't returning anything:  $RefHash['$($Matches[1])'].FileCode.  However, when I run $Matches it returns the value/Identifier.